# Error while importing Theano in Windows

Tags: windows, theano

I am trying to use **Theano** for Deep Learning in Windows 7. I have installed Visual Studio Community Edition 2013 . And CUDA Toolkit 7.5 . I am using Anaconda environment for Python.

But when I import Theano I encounter the following command line message.

```
ERROR:theano.sandbox.cuda:Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu: ('nvcc return statu s', 2, 'for cmd', 'nvcc -shared -O3-LC:\\Users\\hp\\Anaconda2\\libs -use_fast_m ath --compiler-bindir C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\ \bin\\amd64-Xlinker /DEBUG -D HAVE_ROUND -m64 -Xcompiler -DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=187 15462c72ed6afcd7ca5d52813ce90,-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION,/Zi,/MD -IC:\\Users\\hp\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\sandbox\\cuda -IC:\\Us ers\\hp\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include -IC:\\Users\\hp\\An aconda2\\include -IC:\\Users\\hp\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\gof -o C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Theano\\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_60_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-2.7.12-64\\cuda_ndarray\\cuda_ndarray.pyd mod.cu -LC:\\Users\\hp\\Anaconda2\\libs-LC:\\Users\\hp\\Anaconda2 -lcublas  -lpython27 -lcudart')
```

My Config file(.theanorc) looks like this::

```
    [global]
    floatX = float32
    openmp =false
    device = gpu
    mode=FAST_RUN

    [cuda]
    root = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Installer2\CUDAToolkit_7.5


    [nvcc]
    flags = -LC:\Users\hp\Anaconda2\libs
    compiler_bindir = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio12.0\VC\bin\amd64  
    fastmath = True
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the error, but you should change this line:

```
flags = -LC:\Users\hp\Anaconda2\libs
```

It is looking in `-LC:\Users\hp\Anaconda2\libs` instead of `C:\Users\hp\Anaconda2\libs`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use quotes in directories; also, I had similar errors, until I removed the `compliler_bindir` line. I suggest you start with this minimal `.theanorc` file:

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = gpu

[nvcc]
flags=-L"C:\Users\hp\Anaconda2\libs"
```

provided of course that the `flags` path is the correct one...